# How create 1 overlapped by a tilde in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I've invented a custom symbol I wish to use in my LaTeX writings.  It is a one, 1,  overlapped with a tilde.  This image shows what I want:

[image: a digit '1' with overlapping wiggle]

The actual symbol for the tilde is `\sim`.  I have seen `\rlap` used to make characters overlap, as in

```
$\rlap{X}O$
```

which creates 
[image: Capital O and capital X overlapping; ugly vector space product]

but when I try

```
$\rlap{\sim}{1}$
```

I get an error complaining about a missing `$`.  Duh. What is a valid way to get this one+tilde symbol?

I prefer to avoid any uncommon packages or anything quirky, so that the proper LaTeX way of doing this can be used for online markup, such as blogs, wikis, and Q&A forums, which may be using any version of LaTeX and may or may not have any particular desired package.

Comment: Note: the tag "overlays" is incorrect.  I wanted to put "overlap" but don't have the right to do so yet.  I don't know of any other relevant tags.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've suggested a couple of tags that should work. Please be aware that our limited tag set is really by design, I think some kind of overlap tag would probably be much too narrow in my opinion. Others may disagree, but personally I think it's best to keep tags as broad indexes and I can't think of many questions that warrant an overlap tag (perhaps why we don't have one :P)

Comment: 'kerning' perhaps?

Comment: I don't know that it's 'kerning' as such, you could maybe tag it with positioning, but honestly, I wouldn't worry about over-tagging

Comment: 'wild and crazy kerning' then?   Yeah, I'll leave the tagging to others...

Comment: :D Yeah, i think 'wild-and-crazy-kerning' would not be a suitable tag for this site :)

Answer (score 3):

The following example overlays the two symbols:

- The current math style is respected by implementing it via `\mathpalette`.
- The `1` is horizontally centered.
- The tilde is vertically centered.
- The implementation does not need any additional packages.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tildeone}{%
  \mathord{% or whatever
    \mathpalette\@tildeone{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@tildeone}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\sim\m@th$}% tilde
  \sbox2{$#11$}% for height of "1"
  \sbox4{$#1\vcenter{}$}% math axis, presumably the middle of "\sim"
  \rlap{% place "1"
    \hbox to\wd0{\hfil$#11\m@th$\hfil}%
  }%
  % place the tilde raised to the correct height
  \raise\dimexpr.5\ht2 - \ht4\relax\copy0 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ 1 + {\sim} = \tildeone \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Here are three solutions, based on `\mathclap` from `\mathtools` and `\stackinset` from `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}

 \begin{document}

 \[ \mathclap {1}\mathclap{\sim}\qquad \mathclap {1}\mathclap{\raisebox{0.1ex}{$ \sim $}}\qquad \stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{-0.2ex}{$ \sim $}{$ 1 $} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]